# Java equivalent of c function call

Tags: java, c, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am required to convert several dozen mathematical functions into C programs, and then into Java equivalent. I'm not that great in Java so how would we call the following function `double mvfBeale(int n, double *x)` in Java. Is a dynamic array the way to go for **variable x**

Following is a simple program in c, for which I need the Java equivalent to get started.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


double mvfBeale(int n, double *x)
{
    return pow(1.5 - x[0] + x[0]*x[1], 2) +
    pow(2.25 - x[0] + x[0] * x[1]*x[1], 2) +
    pow(2.625 - x[0] + x[0] * pow(x[1], 3), 2);
}


int main(void)
{
    int n;
    double x;
    double result;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    result = mvfBeale(n, &x);
    printf("Beale = %lf", result);

}
```

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: and what is the question ?

Comment: If I understand your question, a normal array would be fine. You'd declare it like `double mvfBeale(int n, double[] x) {...` and call it with `mvfBeale(n, x)`. (Java doesn't exactly have dynamic arrays. It does have things like `ArrayList`s, but these are a bit different.)

Comment: Is the function using the address of a local variable as an array? You certainly can't do _that_ in java...

Comment: With the way you call the function `x[1]` can contain any garbage or accessing it may crash the program, or worse! This is undefined behavior!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java you need to wrap free-standing C functions in a class. You need to declare these functions `static`:

```
public class MathHelper {
    public static double mvfBeale(int n, double[] x)
    {
        return Math.pow(1.5 - x[0] + x[0]*x[1], 2) +
        Math.pow(2.25 - x[0] + x[0] * x[1]*x[1], 2) +
        Math.pow(2.625 - x[0] + x[0] * Math.pow(x[1], 3), 2);
    }
}
```

Note that since `pow` is a free-standing function in C, its Java version needs to refer to it as a member of the [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class.

Comment: You would then call the static method like `MathHelper.mvfBeale(4,x)`